# why the name of the Controls in ItemsControl not displaying in Codebehind file in Wpf

Tags: wpf

i Created simple sample using the ItemsControl and DataTemplate.. i want to bind the values using the C# code in textblocs.But i didn't get the textblock names and Datatemplate names in Code behind file please tell me why.. What to do to get the names of the controls ?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemp">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 

<TextBlock  x:Name="Textblock1" Text="{Binding }" FontWeight="Bold" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" x:Name="Textblock2"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" x:Name="Textblock3"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

but here in Code file Textblock1 and other names not dispalying even i used the "Name" only Instead of "x:Name "

Comment: What do you want to do with the data template and textblock?

Answer (score 0):

No member will be generated for the DataTemplate. A datatemplate is just used for instantiating items dynamically at runtime, so the Controls don't even exist until you add items to your ItemsControl, and even then i think the names of individual controls inside the DataTemplate are just useful for usage from inside the DataTemplate's markup.

Comment: Thank you..So i can't use them(controls in DT) out side the DataTempletes. Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate names, if needed when the ItemsControl is loaded.

```
    private void OnPopupItemsLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsControl = sender as ItemsControl;

        itemsControl.ApplyTemplate();
        var numItems = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.Items.Count();
        for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
        {
            var container = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            textBlock = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(container);
            if (textBlock != null)
            {
                textBlock.Name = SanitizeName(textBlock.Text);
                textBlock.Uid = $"Item{i}";
            }
        }
    }

    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    return (T)child;
                }

                T childItem = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childItem != null)
                {
                    return childItem;
                }
            }
        }

        // None found
        return null;
    }

    // FrameworkeElement.Name must start with an underscore or letter and
    // only contain letters, digits, or underscores.
    private string SanitizeName(string textString)
    {
        // Text may start with a digit
        var sanitizedName = "_";

        foreach (var c in textString)
        {
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            {
                sanitizedName += c;
            }
            else
            {
                sanitizedName += "_";
            }
        }

        return sanitizedName;
    }
```